# Looking for a Chromium Command Line Switch to relax HTMLInputElement restrictions

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

The title pretty much says it all. Is there a command line switch for Chrome/Edge which relaxes the restrictions that are made to javascript on the input element of type file?

- Yes I am aware there is a reason for these restrictions
- No I actually don't intend to use it on a Browser such as Chrome or Edge

I want to know so I can build a hybrid app that utilizes MS's Webview2 which accepts the switches (at least I am led to believe it does)

**EDIT:** I want to call click() and/or add files to it.

Comment: Please can you [edit] to explain what restrictions you're trying to disable, or better, what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Done. But I assume there is no switch.